# Unable to parse through sqlite query using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate through a database and match all rows that have 02 in them using regular expressions. When a match is made the count should reset to 0 and when there is not a match the count should accumulate by negative 1. The code works when I use a list.

```
import sqlite3
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect('p34.db')

c = conn.cursor()



r = re.compile(r'\b[5-9]*(?:0[5-9]?2|2[5-9]?0)[5-9]*\b')
q = "SELECT Number FROM 'Pick 3'"



c.execute(q)
rez = c.fetchall()
count = 0 


for i in rez:
    if i == r:
        count = 0
    else:
        count = count -1

print(count)
conn.close()
print (rez)
```

Comment: `i == r` is invalid for regex matching. You need to use the regex methods here like [search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [`r.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to execute a regular expression search:

```
for i in rez:
    if r.search(i[0]):
        count = 0
    else:
        count -= 1
```

Note the use of `i[0]` to get the first value from each tuple returned by the query.

Using `i == r` simply *compares* the tuple `i` (as returned by the query) to the compiled regular expression patter `r` and will never be true. It does not execute any of the search methods of the given pattern.